# Make sv_cheats 1 exclusive to me on gmod?

Tags: cheats, garrys-mod

So I want to put sv_cheats 1 on my server on gmod but when I do everyone can use it. Is there anyway only the creator of the server can be the only one to use the cheats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sv_cheats is a server side flag.  That means it's set for everyone that connects to the server, no exceptions.  You likely want to do some investigation into Admin Mods like [ULX](http://gmod.gamebanana.com/tuts/11079) and Evolve which can give you cheat like abilities but only for "Administrator" users you choose.

Comment: Will ULX and Evolve work for non dedicated servers? My server uses hamachi

Comment: Listen servers will work, most of the time it's simpler since by default the owner of the listen server will be set as an admin.

Comment: Is ULX and evolve an add on or is it something you have to download (like a .exe)

Comment: You will have to [download](http://ulyssesmod.net/archive/ulx/install-ulx-v3_61.exe) it and install it.  There are numerous guides and YouTube videos detailing how to install and setup the mod.